# How many ways are there of arranging the letters in the word

Tags: probability, self-study, combinatorics

I am trying to understand my exercise but I still couldn't understand my teacher so I wonder if anyone please can help me?

How many ways are there of arranging the letters in the word BANANA?
The answer was
6! / (3!2!)

I get the 6! but I dont understand why it isn't 3!3!, why 2!?
Thank you for your help

Comment: You're dividing-out by the 3! permutations of the 3 A's and the 2! permutations of the 2 N's.

Comment: Check out the multinomial coefficient

Comment: @Creosote what about B? is it cos B! = 1 can get omitted?

Comment: Yes. that's right.  You are in fact doing 6! / (3!2!1!), but it's normal not to bother writing the 1! part of that explicitly.